# Adding Line breaking PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, newline

I'm trying to add a new line in a PHP code but all to no avail. I've tried \r\n and even tried using the HTML break like but it's just not working. These are the ones I tried:

```
$message .= '<br>Thank you for registering. <br>';
```

in other cases I tried:

```
$message .= nl2br('\r\n Thank you for registering. \r\n ');
```

I really don't know much about coding and I'll really appreciate the help.

The question has been answered in one of the comments!

Comment: does `$message .= PHP_EOL. 'Thank you for registering.' . PHP_EOL;` work?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? You are putting breaking lines before and after text, so maybe just you don't recognize it... try `$message .= 'Thank you<br>for registering. '` instead to check if it works.

Comment: This worked!! Thank you! @Timberman

Comment: @biesior That doesn't solve it because It still shows <br> in the user's message no matter which part I place it. when I used PHP_EOL. it worked.

Comment: You didn't show us how do you display your message, if it's handled by some script or templating engine it can escape inner HTML, what happened in your case. Next time, pls write such details in the original question, so we don't need to guess.

Comment: My apologies for the misunderstanding. That was why I had put the WordPress tag. It's in WordPress. Technically a WordPress plugin code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone commented with this:

```
$message .= PHP_EOL. 'Thank you for registering.'. PHP_EOL;
```

And it's working perfectly.